# Validación del campo nombre con espacios en blanco

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, webforms

Estoy haciendo una validación en un campo "Nombre" con expresiones regulares, pero el problema es que cuando hay un espacio entre 2 o 3 nombres me sale el "alert" diciendo que no estoy validando bien.

```
var reg = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;

    if (!(reg.test($("#txtNombres").val().trim()))) {
        alert("Ingrese solo letras en el campo 'Nombres'");
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: ¿Los nombres en que idioma están? ¿Castellano?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EL problema se ve que está en tu expresión regular en sí ya que nunca tomas en cuenta los espacios en blanco, te recomiendo usar esta:

```
/^[ÁÉÍÓÚA-Z][a-záéíóú]+(\s+[ÁÉÍÓÚA-Z]?[a-záéíóú]+)*$/
```

Explicación:

[image: máquina de estados de regex propuesto]

Como verás en esta expresión regular tomamos en cuenta que en castellano los nombres propios inician con el primer caractér en mayúscula, seguido de uno o más caracteres en minúscula, opcionalmente tenemos apellidos, que pueden iniciar o no con mayúsculas y se separan del nombre y entre si con uno o más espacio(s) en blanco antes.

Algunos ejemplos válidos serían:

- José Von Newman de la Luz
- Ruslan López
- Mao Rivera Sánchez Armas
- Sinapellidos

Comment: GRACIAS AMIGO, ME SALVASTE LA VIDA :)

Comment: El de Sinapellidos me llama más la atención porque hay algunos usuarios que no ponen ese dato.

Comment: [Nota curiosa en México hay 5.534 personas sin apellidos](https://www.infobae.com/america/mexico/2018/07/01/millones-de-hernandez-y-5-500-personas-sin-apellidos-las-curiosidades-de-la-lista-de-electores-en-mexico/), no es un error, es una forma de ser más inclusivos :)

Answer (score 1):

Podrías utilizar esto: que busca también diacríticos. `^(([^\s.,:;]+)\s?)+$`

https://regex101.com/r/zyKgP9/2

Comment: GRACIAS POR ESTA REFERENCIA, SI O SI TAMBIÉN ME SERVIRÁ :D